# Sending 2D JavaScript array to PHP via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send a 2D array to PHP via AJAX and then access the content in PHP. I have the following setup for creating the 2D array:

```
var data = [];
data['items1'] = ["item1_1", "item1_2"];
data['items2'] = ["item2_1", "item2_2"];
```

I then send this info to PHP via Ajax like this which works fine (I get to the case "my_php_case")

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_site_url, 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: "my_php_case",
        data: data,
    },
    success: function(response) { 
    },
});
```

Now I want to access say "items1" on the PHP side and tried the following which gave an empty result:

```
$items1 = $_POST['data']['items1'];
```

I have tried JSON.stringify on `data` and then use `json_decode` on PHP side but still not working. I can only find more complex cases online when searching and just want this simple case to work.

How can I send and access the data with my Ajax call?

Comment: Try to see the actual content of the `$_POST` variable by using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. This docs about the `.ajax()` method (especially the `data` option description) may give you additional hints about why you have this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @indyteo, I don't see anything, where do the print_r or var_dump go? I don't find in console nor on screen.

Comment: Check the network tab. That will show you what is being sent and received. At this point you are probably just getting errors.

Comment: `data['items1']` is not adding an item to an array, that is what you would do if `data` was an object literal. To add to an array use `data.push(["item1_1", "item1_2"])`

Comment: @JasonK, As mentioned in the post I get no errors when sending the data. The problem is I don't know how to pack/unpack it.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Javascript are numerically indexed so you can't add string keys as it appears you are doing above. To use string keys change `data` to an Object Literal and then use `JSON.stringify` prior to sending the ajax request.

```js
var ajax_site_url=location.href;
var data = {};
    data['items1'] = ["item1_1", "item1_2"];
    data['items2'] = ["item2_1", "item2_2"];
    
console.log( data );

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_site_url,
    data: {
        action: "my_php_case",
        data: JSON.stringify( data ),
    },
    success:(res)=>alert('Success:\n'+res),
    error:(err)=>alert('Error:\n'+err)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, using an array means in PHP you would not longer be able to access using `items1` as per your requirement.

```js
var ajax_site_url=location.href;
var data = [];
    data.push( ["item1_1", "item1_2"] );
    data.push( ["item2_1", "item2_2"] );
    
console.log( data );

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_site_url,
    data: {
        action: "my_php_case",
        data: JSON.stringify( data ),
    },
    success:(res)=>alert('Success:\n'+res),
    error:(err)=>alert('Error:\n'+err)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

In response to your comments I put together this simple demo of the above. When executed this will output `Items1 Item_1=item1_1 Items2 Item_2=item2_2` to the browser. The Javascript is virtually identical to that shown above except for a modified callback function - otherwise it is the same.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( 
        $_POST['action'],
        $_POST['data']
    )){

        $json=json_decode( $_POST['data'] );
        
        echo 'Items1 Item_1=' . $json->items1[0] . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Items2 Item_2=' . $json->items2[1];
        
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Basic JSON & AJAX</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <output></output>
        <script>
        
            var ajax_site_url=location.href;
            var data = {};
                data['items1'] = ["item1_1", "item1_2"];
                data['items2'] = ["item2_1", "item2_2"];
                
            console.log( data );

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax_site_url,
                data: {
                    action: "my_php_case",
                    data: JSON.stringify( data ),
                },
                success:(res)=>{
                    console.info(res)
                    document.querySelector('output').textContent=res;
                },
                error:(err)=>alert('Error:\n'+err)
            });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should encode the whole `data` object as JSON, instead of `data.data` (I agree that this naming choice may lead to unclear situations...)

Comment: I tried using your first approach and then print the data in PHP as $_POST['data']['items1'] but get "{" as result. Do I need to do something in PHP to unpack the stringified variable?

Comment: I also tried to json_decode on php like this: $data = json_decode($_POST['data']); and then use $data['items1'] but that gives me an empty result.

Comment: In the php you need to do a $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], True); To put it an an associated array.